# On creating checkbox in php, only Only one checkbox is displayed in the div by ajax on receiving the data.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created checkboxes in php:

```
    $check =array();
    $id=1;
    while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $check[]= "<input id='checkoverlay".$id."' name='overlaycheckbox' 
        value='overlaycheck'  class='olButton' type='checkbox'>
        <label class='labelSpan olButton' style='vertical-align: bottom'>".$result['title']."<br>";
        $id++;
}
echo json_encode($check);
```

When I receive the data in ajax, I get an array which I again loop to extract the checkboxes I successfully created in php. But the problem is only 1 checkbox is shown: the last one. Maybe the variable is getting the latest value and displaying it erasing the earlier one, but I am unable to get other data.

```
    $.ajax({
            type:"Post",
            url:"query.php",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
                    check= data[i];
                    console.log(check);
                    $('.div').html(check);
                 }
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are overwriting your data each time. You need to use `.append()`instead of `.html()`. So change your ajax code as below:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"Post",
            url:"query.php",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                $('.div').html(""); //initialize
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
                    check= data[i];
                    console.log(check);
                    $('.div').append(check);
                 }
            }
});
```